# Can't get the corresponding values of some items stored within json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get different items from json response from a webpage. I've partially got success by collecting the name of different items. However, I wish to get the different price of it. When it comes to parse the corresponding values of each item, I've got stuck. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

site address: [web_link](https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerAll)

Script I've tried with:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("replace_with_above_url")
for items in res.json():
    for name in items:
        print(name)
```

This is how the structure look like:

```
[{"BTC":{"sellPrice":711500,"buyPrice":711150,"lastTradePrice":711150}},{"XRP":{"sellPrice":76.7,"buyPrice":76.6,"lastTradePrice":76.6}},{"NEO":{"sellPrice":8769,"buyPrice":8651,"lastTradePrice":8769}},{"GAS":{"sellPrice":3140,"buyPrice":3105,"lastTradePrice":3105}},{"ETH":{"sellPrice":63500,"buyPrice":62450.01,"lastTradePrice":63500}},{"XLM":{"sellPrice":30.78,"buyPrice":30.61,"lastTradePrice":30.78}}]
```

Output I'm having (only):

```
BTC
XRP
NEO
```

Output I intend to get:

```
BTC 711500 711150 711150
XRP 76.7    76.6   76.6
so on ---
```

Comment: try `print(name,items[name]['sellPrice'],items[name]['buyPrice'],items[name]['lastTradePrice'])`

Comment: @Yunus Saha, yes, it does solve the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
r = requests.get('https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerAll')
for item in r.json():
    for key, value in item.items():
        print(key, value['sellPrice'], value['buyPrice'], value['lastTradePrice'])
```

Output:

```
BTC 705000 704000 704000
XRP 72.3 72.29 72.29
NEO 8452 8450 8452
GAS 3060 3024 3024
ETH 61000 60700 60700
XLM 29.8 29.78 29.78
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

> When looping through dictionaries, the key and corresponding value can be retrieved at the same time using the `items()` method.

Comment: Wow!! very nice solution. Thanks @Keyur Potdar for your solution along with the link to the docs. Sometimes, it is really difficult to find the right portion of a documentation when in need. +1 for the link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I feel is that you need to understand that you are trying to print in the second loop. If you print in the first iteration, you can see the following result.

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerAll")
for items in res.json():
    print(items)

{'BTC': {'sellPrice': 703500, 'buyPrice': 702000, 'lastTradePrice': 702000}}
{'XRP': {'sellPrice': 72.89, 'buyPrice': 72.7, 'lastTradePrice': 72.9}}
{'NEO': {'sellPrice': 8480, 'buyPrice': 8400, 'lastTradePrice': 8400}}
{'GAS': {'sellPrice': 3000, 'buyPrice': 2990, 'lastTradePrice': 2990}}
{'ETH': {'sellPrice': 61499, 'buyPrice': 60800, 'lastTradePrice': 60800}}
{'XLM': {'sellPrice': 29.6, 'buyPrice': 29.53, 'lastTradePrice': 29.53}}
```

Now you need to iterate through the second object, so you can use the following code.

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://bitbns.com/order/getTickerAll")
for item in res.json():
    for key,value in item.items():
        print(key, value)
        for subkey,subvalue in value.items():
            print(subkey,subvalue)
```

The second and third for loops are coming because of Python's assumption that dictionary by definition has arbitrary number of keys. You can continue to drill down as much as you want or follow the previous answer where you have got the exact result as you want.

Comment: Another good solution. I wish I could accept both the answers!! Thanks @Haris Np.